# Why is 'og:type' of 'articel' invalid

Tags: facebook, types

Hello why is my og:type invalid ?

Here is the Link to the debug: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=vote-it.de

And here for the Website in the Meta tags in the beginning is everything ok or ?

Answer (score 2):

You have a misspelling. It should be `article` not `articel`

```html
<meta property="og:type" content="article">
```